# Can I speed finding indexes of an array more than what I have?

Tags: c#, performance, list, indexing

I am keeping vertices in a list, I only want to add a vertices into the list if it does not already contain it.  if it doesnt contain it I will add it to the list then add the index to a list called tris.  However if the list does contain the vertices already it should find the index of where its located and then just add that index to the tris list.  Here is the fastest way of doing this that I have figured out.  is there any faster way?

```
Hashtable vertIndexes;
List<Vector3> verts;
List<int> tris;

foreach (var vert in vertsOutput)
{
    Vector3 p = point + vert;
    if(!vertIndexes.Contains(p))
    {
        vertIndexes.Add(p, verts.Count);
        tris.Add(verts.Count);
        verts.Add(p);
    }
    else
    {
        tris.Add((int)vertIndexes[p]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I read that using `for` with an index is faster than `foreach`. Other than that you could use a `Dictionary<Vector3>`, which makes finding the vertex O(1).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - Hashtable has O(1) as well, its just not generic as Dictionary<> so you're paying for boxing/unboxing. Also the Hashtable (or Dictionary<>) should be allocated to have capacity greater than actual fill - 1/3 ratio is best from my personal experience.

Comment: i agree with @ThorstenDittmar, but rather than a dictionary i would go with a `HashSet<Vector3>`

Comment: @SpookKruger I tried HashSet<Vector3> first the only problem with that was I could not get a index from that so there was no way to put a index in the tri list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you are performing two hashtable operations per items. You can save one:

```
Dictionary<Vector3, int> vertIndexes;
...

int index;
if(vertIndexes.TryGetValue(p, out index))
 //present at given index
else
 //not present
```

`TryGetValue` simultaneously tests for existence and returns the stored value.

You can probably go faster with a custom hash table. `Dictionary` has some overheads in it that are required for generality and that you don't need. For example, the modulus operator it uses is surprisingly expensive and unnecessary with a good hash code. This is beyond the scope of this answer, though.

Comment: I didn't notice much performance boost using this, ill try a custom hashtable later, maybe there is something else that is slowing it down?

Comment: Very well possible. Profile the code, or just pause the debugger 10 times to see where it stops most often.; Maybe you are frequently taking the case where you add to the dict. With a custom hashtable you can write a customized operation that combines all operations into one lookup. Use a power-of-two array size so that you can quickly calculate the correct bucket index as `hashCode & (length - 1)`. Much faster than modulo.

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of containers, and they all have different performance, resource, and utilization characteristics.

A List is not the fastest container for lookups.  A dictionary or Hashset may be better.  But it depends on how you need to use it.

If you need to look up the vertex by a key, then use a dictionary.  If the vertex is itself the key then use a hashtable for that as well.  Then you don't need the separate hashtable for indexes.

Do you actually need the count?  If not, then just use a hashtable for the vertexes, if you need the count then use a dictionary keyed on the vertex with count.  `Dictionary<Vertex3,int>`

Comment: all I need in the end is two arrays, one with the vector3s and another with the indexes to point to the vectors to create triangles with

Comment: @Shredder2500 - I don't really know much about 3D rendering, but why do you need an array of indexes into a different array?  Is that an ordinal number or actual references?  Because if it's actual references, how is that any different from the actual list of vertexes?

Comment: Unity will go through the triangle array get the index in that triangle list and find the vert in the vert array. the verts can be in any order but the tris order tell it how to render the triangles

Comment: Again.. are these ordinal indexes?  Or are they references?